# Android 4 UrlConnection setReadTimeout does not work on VPN connections

Tags: android, urlconnection

I try to setReadTimeout on UrlConnection on 60000. THe server continually sends an keep alive. Some time (could be hours) this stops working. Even better: NO exception is thrown. The code just sits there, no connectionTImeout no readTimeout, no nothing exception, and the keep alive is no written into the logfile.

Does anyone experience this? Any workaround, other than writing a watchdog to monitor this process?
Thanks for any advice.
Hannes